# How to change where GVim looks for syntax.vim on windows

Tags: vim

When I try to use `:syntax on` I get the following error:
`E484: Can't open file C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\gvim.exe\syntax\snytax.vim`

When I explore the directory, I find that there is a syntax.vim at the directory:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\syntax\syntax.vim`

How do I get gVim to recognize that this is where it should look for the syntax files?

I am using windows 10.

Comment: Vim is supposed to source `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\syntax\syntax.vim`. If it doesn't then you might have found a bug. Try [the issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues).

Comment: @romainl You really think I encountered a new bug? Any other ideas on what I could try to fix it? Maybe a re-install?

Comment: New or not, what happens is not what should happen and your question is unrelated to programming anyway. Use the issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl in case you're interested, we found the problem and solution, you were right about vim being supposed to source `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\syntax\syntax.vim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Tomoki helped me find the answer.

In windows 10, type `environment variables` in the search bar
click `Edit the system environment variables`

Under the `Advanced` tab, click `Environment variables`

Under the `System variables` section, find the `vim` or `Vim` system variable, and edit the `Variable value` so that it says `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\gvim.exe`

it should not have been pointing at the executable in the first place, which is why it could not find a syntax at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\gvim.exe\syntax\snytax.vim`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
You have to set <del>$VIMRUNTIME</del>  (Not this variable, as Stun Brick points out in the comment below.) as an environment variable.
If you are using Windows 10, search on your compuer, "Edit the system environment variables" and you can set it.

Comment: Should I add a new environment variable called `$VIMRUNTIME` and what should the value of the variable be?

Comment: I have finally found the answer to this problem that has plagued me for a year, thanks to you! It turns out that it was my environment variables in windows were the problem, but it had nothing to do with `$VIMRUNTIME`, it was the `vim` environment variable that was pointing at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\gvim.exe` when it should've just pointed at the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82`.

I'll give you an upvote and edit your answer to be the correct one, then if you accept the proposed changes, i'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I couldn't edit your comment as the edit queue is full, so i'll have to post an answer.